# Replace an impolite phrase for making up facts on the fly

Tags: phrase-request, british-english

I was talking to a group and something happened and I had to quickly enhance my narrative to fit some new facts. I wanted to say
"I am not bull-shitting this is true"

but realised I didn't want to say bull-shitting in front of my young kids.

That was 3 days ago and I still haven't come up with a polite way to say this, I am looking to replace "bull-shitting" in the above sentence.

I did consider lying but just felt it didn't have the full story telling/ trying to convince somebody meaning that bull-shitting conveys.
There is blagging, but that feels to mean trying to gain entry to somewhere

Comment: I am not faking this, or making this up.

Comment: You might consider a thesaurus. One of my favorites is "telling porkies." This comes from Cockney rhyming slang: Porkies, meaning pork pies, meaning lies.  There are huge numbers of possible alternatives for telling a lie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best words for your blank is **joking**:

> I’m not joking - she sent me a slide deck like 8 hours later. — [Pediatric Support](https://forum.pediatricsupport.com/t/leveraging-patient-tools-during-covid-interview-with-dr-barbara-howard/3900)

While this has a slightly different connotation than *BSing*, it's often used as an exact synonym when you didn't say anything particularly funny but people might think you were exaggerating. Same for "[not kidding](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I%27m+not+kidding)". Also "I'm not lying":

> Yes sir. Its scientific name is a Smaug Giganteus. I'm not lying. It's actually Smaug — [Twitter](https://twitter.com/mkahn13/status/511713581264412672?lang=en)

(And in fact that's backed up by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_girdled_lizard). The name of the lizard, not per se the word choice.)

If you change your sentence a bit, you can also use something along the lines of "[no joke](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=no%20joke)" or "no lie", which are both a little bit more informal:

> No lie it's been the best, better than any body cream, or lotion I ever use. — [Shea Joy review](https://sheajoy.com/products/pink-cashmere-body-butter)

> No joke he actually argued against abolishing the state on a recent stream — [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Enough_Vaush_Spam/comments/lww71w/no_joke_he_actually_argued_against_abolishing_the/)